# Alternative to path based access control in Subversion

Tags: svn, itar

Is there any alternative to path based access control in Subversion?

I'm dealing with a repository that contains files that are subject to [ITAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations). Several teams will have access to the repository, but some of them are not allowed to even **see** ITAR sensitive data, so we're talking about read access here, not just commit access.

Now I have several options for dealing with this.

The first is simply listing out all the files that have access restrictions. The problem with that is that we need to know what the filename is going to be before it can be added to the auth file. So a developer creates an ITAR sensitive file, e-mails the full path to the svn admin, who then adds it to the auth file. Only then can the developer actually add and commit the file.

Another solution is to have two directories at the top level, say `general` and `mil`, with the same subdirectories. That way, all sensitive files go into `mil` and all others go into `general`. That gives me a short and sweet auth file, but the downside is that if a file *becomes* ITAR sensitive, it needs to be moved from one tree to the other. We can work with that, but it's not optimal.

What I would *like* to have, is property based access control. If we could just add a property, say `mil` or `itar:reason` to a file and restrict access based on that, that would be ideal. Developers could add the property before first commit, or when a file becomes sensitive. However, except if I have missed it, that's not possible.

So does anyone see any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that even properties will do the trick, as they are versioned.  So if you add a file and forget to set the property right away, a clever user could retrieve an earlier version of the file.  You'd have to be willing to scrub the offending data from your dump file, which of course requires some down time.

Anyway, that's a problem you'll hit with almost any solution if someone makes a mistake and puts a file in the wrong place, in the wrong repo, or with the wrong properties.  If you know some property of the ITAR files then you could write a hook to prevent them being put into the wrong part of the repository.  Then you can look at solutions based on 'known sensitive' paths or even separate repositories and externals.

Otherwise you can look at putting a proxy in front of Apache that knows all the sensitive files, regardless of when they were designated as sensitive, and scrubs them out of the traffic for unauthorized users.  It's a tricky problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternative to path based access control in Subversion

I don't know of a read-access restriction based soly on file properties.

> the downside is that if a file becomes ITAR sensitive, it needs to be moved from one tree to the other.

That cannot be avoided, or easily automated without "race condition": you could set a property on that file, and have a cron job moving any file found in general to mil, but that means until that cron job runs, anyone having access to mil can have a look at that file.

An on-demand move between the two top folders (which acts like branches) is better.
The closest you can get to automate that move is by:

- setting a property on the file
- having an **[`svn post-revprop` hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-revprop-change.html)** running, which would detect that special property and do the move for you.

Comment: What I meant by property based access control, was actually ignoring the path and having svn look at the properties and restrict access based on them. That's probably best handled as a feature request.
But in the meantime, your suggestion with the automated post-revprop move, isn't a bad idea.

Comment: @SQB I understand, and never saw an property based access control, hence my hook suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for that. Problem in general is that the subversion approach is most likely based on an open source software point of view, where everyone is allowed to read the source. Read access control was probably a by-product of commit access control, where path based access makes sense, since that boils down to project based access control.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to use a hook. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer.

Comment: @SQB no problem. I would be curious as to how that proxy would be implemented. If you make it work, post an answer in this page to explain how.

Comment: I'll try to remember to do so, but _if_ we do, it'll be a while before that actually happens.