# What mechanisms do different VCS's have for restricting access to files?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, itar

[I have asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723242/alternative-to-path-based-access-control-in-subversion), but that was within the context of Subversion only. As there is a possibility that we'll move to a different VCS, I'll ask again with a broader scope.

We're dealing with a repository that contains files that are subject to [ITAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations). Several teams will have access to the repository, but some of them are not allowed to even **see** ITAR sensitive data, so we're talking about read access here, not just commit access.

What we'd like to have, is access control where we can restrict access

- Right away (on commit)
- Post hoc (marking an already committed file as sensitive, if possible)
- Version based (if possible)

A scenario could be:
Version 148 is not sensitive and is accessible to everybody
Version 149 *is* sensitive and should be inaccessible to those without clearance, right after commit.
Version 150 is not sensitive anymore and is again accessible to everybody.

Is there any VCS (preferably a *D* VCS) that provides these options?

---

Additional information: we're doing Scrum. There are four teams, doing their sprints out of sync with each other. There has been talk of synchronizing our sprints.
There is some overlap in the code the teams handle, but not much.
We want to move to continous integration some time in the future, but we've a long way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll ever find a DVCS that does what you want -- each copy of the repo needs to have all the code (and history).  I suppose in theory, it's possible (encrypt each file, then manage the keys, etc.). But the management overhead would probably be equivalent to saying "Before you check in an ITAR file, encrypt it with a key only people in the US know."

Your best bet is to go modular and put all ITAR code in one repo. (Often, there will be a 'stub' implementation in a regular repo that uses null encryption or whatever.) Then you can do absolute read access control for that repo.

You can also apply for an ITAR exemption. Sometimes having the software on a computer that blocks IPs from bad countries is enough. It's a long shot, but it would simplify your life.

Possibly relevant: In the 90's Sun Microsystems realized that ITAR only hampers US programmers. So they [developed encryption software exclusively outside of the US](http://special.pacificresearch.org/pub/sab/techno/encrypt/part4.html) as a simple way to "get around" ITAR.